# Scheduling of Java Opc-UaClient Eclipse Milo not working

Tags: java, ejb, job-scheduling, opc-ua, quartz

I am facing a strange issue while working with OPC UA client in EJB.

I need to create background service which will communicate with OPC Server after an interval. I am using Quartz API for scheduling in EJB.

Scheduling is working properly but when I call OPCUA Server using class which implements ClientExample then I am able to get data only two time.

On third call the error occurs which lead to automatic Server Shutdown.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Do you have anything more helpful? Error messages from the client or server. Information about the server?

Comment: @KevinHerron I am using Wildfly server 10. I am getting below error in server log

Comment: `15:02:00,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
15:02:00,364 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) WFLYMSGAMQ0006: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
15:02:00,367 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /OpcClientService-websample`

Comment: @KevinHerron Please let me know if you need any other details. Waiting for your valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. The way we were communicating with OPC server was wrong.

There should be only one session for each OPC Server endpoint throughout the application. We need to use this connected session for Scheduling and Monitoring or other required features.